# Перестал работать pip после попытки обновления: ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead

Tags: python, pip

Хотел обновить свой модуль requests при помощи команды *pip install requests --upgrade*, но что-то случилось и теперь у меня сломался pip. При попытке сделать pip install requests или вообще установить любой другой пакет, получаю ошибки:

```
root@goodwin:~# pip --upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

Comment: ответ дан [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341064/how-do-i-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-incompleteread)

Comment: @MaxU Всё равно не работает 
`root@goodwin:~# easy_install pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point`

Comment: удалить pip, и установить его через easy_install

Comment: @vadimvaduxa сделал всё, как указал пользователь выше. Пишу easy_install pip и появляются следующие ошибки.

Comment: Как pip установлен? Вы глобально обновляли? Virtualenv по строке консоли не видно. Система какая? Если debian-based то попробуйте переуставновить пакет python-pip.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How do I fix 'ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27341064/4279) Попробуйте [вот этот ответ (переставьте python-requests python-pip системные пакеты)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27341813/4279). Не запускайте pip от root пользователя на Ubuntu. В системные области ставьте пакеты с помощью apt-get. pip используйте для установки в virtualenv или для отдельных пользователей (`--user`). В противном случае, легко сломать системные утилиты такие как apt-get (которые на Питоне могут быть реализованы)